# Why is my program not running through the first while loop?

Tags: function, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a code that counts the total carries of a long division problem. This is the function I wrote for the carries. I believe the problem us that the first while loop not functioning all the way through. If so why is that? This is in Python 3.5.

```
carries = 0
sum1 = 0
countx = str(x)
county = str(y) 
countx1 = len(countx)
county1 = len(county)
countx2 = int(countx1)
county2 = int(county1)
carry_over = 0
count = countx1
index = 1
index1 = 1
carrieslist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
while (index1 <= county1):
    sum3 = county[-index1]
    while (index <= count):
        sum2 = countx[0-index]
        sum4 = int(sum2)
        sum5 = int(sum3)
        sum1 = sum4*sum5+carry_over
        sum6 = str(sum1)
        index = index+1
        if (sum1 > 9):
            carries += 1
            carry_over = int(sum6[0])
            if carry_over > 0:
                if carry_over == 1:
                    carrieslist[1] += 1
                if carry_over == 2:
                    carrieslist[2] += 1
                if carry_over == 3:
                    carrieslist[3] += 1
                if carry_over == 4:
                    carrieslist[4] += 1
                if carry_over == 5:
                    carrieslist[5] += 1
                if carry_over == 6:
                    carrieslist[6] += 1
                if carry_over == 7:
                    carrieslist[7] += 1
                if carry_over == 8:
                    carrieslist[8] += 1  
                if carry_over == 9:
                    carrieslist[9] += 1
        else:
            carry_over = 0
    index1 = index1 + 1
print(" ")
print("Carries:",carries)
print(" ")
if sum(carrieslist) > 0:
    print("Carry digit --> Frequency")
countlist = 0
indexlist = 0
while (countlist < len(carrieslist)): 
    if (carrieslist[indexlist] > 0):
        print(indexlist,"-->",carrieslist[indexlist])
        indexlist += 1
        countlist += 1
    else:
        indexlist += 1
        countlist += 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a negative index in the line, county[-index1]? What is the actual problem you are facing here? By the way what is x and y? What you actually want to do?

Comment: x and y are the two numbers I am multiplying with long multiplication so for example 9929 and 129. And I'm just curious as to why it counts the carries for the 9 x 9929 but doesn't keep going with the carries for the 2 and the 1 in 129. Hopefully that makes sense I can always post the prompt if needed

Comment: Sorry but your explanation is not clear to me. Can you explain what you meant by "counts the total carries of a long division problem" in your post?

Comment: Ok here is the example given: When multiplying two digits, if the product is greater than 9, then there is a carry (e.g., 6 × 4 = 24, where 2 is a carry digit).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I posted the answer below. By the way you have written unnecessarily a big code, you could have solved this problem in more simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem. Just initialize the variable index = 1 inside the outer while loop as follows.

```
while (index1 <= county1):
    sum3 = county[-index1]
    index = 1
    while (index <= count):
        sum2 = countx[0-index]
        sum4 = int(sum2)
        ................
        ................
```

Please improve your coding style so that the codes become more readable. It took a lot of time for me to find the problem as it was difficult to understand what you have written in each statement.

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for the scrambled up code